# Cannot install anything using Brew

Tags: curl, homebrew

I think since I updated my Mac to Big Sur, my brew is broken. Every time I try to install something I get the following

```
curl: (35) error:1400410B:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:wrong version number
```

Sample command outpout:

```
brew install fish
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/pcre2-10.36.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
#=#=#                                                                         
curl: (35) error:1400410B:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:wrong version number
Error: Failed to download resource "pcre2"
Download failed: https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/pcre2-10.36.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
```

I have tried uninstalling Brew and installing again but no luck.

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar problem when installed git by 'brew install git' after I upgraded my mac to BigSur.
The CommandLineTools is not installed default in BigSur.
I executed 'xcode-select --install' then the problem was resolved.

Comment: It needs a lot of space on mac, don't execute this command without knowing what it is.